# Opensips is listenning port 5060, but NMap shows 5060 is closed, Opensips can't receive REGISTER

Tags: sip, opensips

***I got Opensips on an Ubuntu Cloud Server, it is listenning the port 5060.***

sudo netstat -lpn | grep opensips

tcp        0      0 42.123.76.60:5060       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5177/opensips

udp        0      0 42.123.76.60:5060       0.0.0.0:*                           5177/opensips

***But I test on the remote pc client with tools, and shows that the 5060 was closed:***

[enter link description here](http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to checking the port status!!

nmap -p5060 42.123.76.60

PORT     STATE  SERVICE

5060/tcp closed sip

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.21 seconds

***I am wondering that will it results to nothing received from sip clients***

***Jitsi on my pc sended REGISTER, meanwhile, the remote Opensips got nothing.***

***Thanks for your attention, I really appreciate your help!***

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented any firewall? Try "iptables -F"